# Set Sheets filter with Apps Script onEdit using batchUpdate

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following example works fine when you manually run the setFilter() function:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vSDdXU8XSnfG5ixjaMtDys1ynwpbKTptPb_ZFjuMASg/edit#gid=0

```
function setFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var filterSettings = {};

  // The range of data on which you want to apply the filter.
  // optional arguments: startRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endRowIndex, endColumnIndex
  filterSettings.range = {
    sheetId: ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
  };

  // Criteria for showing/hiding rows in a filter
  // https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria
  filterSettings.criteria = {};
  var columnIndex = 2;
  filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
    'hiddenValues': ["England", "France"]
  };

  var request = {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filterSettings
    }
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
}
```

But the function doesn't work within `onEdit()`

```
function onEdit(e){
  setFilter();
}
```

Does `batchUpdate` not work in `onEdit`?

Comment: you can create [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) for the `setFilter` function.

Comment: Quote from documentation:  **Because simple triggers fire automatically, without asking the user for authorization, they are subject to several restrictions**  You are using a simple trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sandy Good said, a simple trigger such as `onEdit` cannot perform any action that requires authorization, e.g., modify a spreadsheet.

Instead, [install a trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that runs on every edit: it will run with your authorization and will be able to do anything you can do by running the function manually.

Comment: Got it, will do, would be nice if an error was thrown when you try to perform action that requires authorization instead of just failing silently